# Cannot set Dropdown Selected Index: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'selectedIndex')

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url-parameters

It should be very easy but don't figure out where the problem is. I need to get the value from an url parameter then make the the dropdown list's option selected based on index number.
The URL is something like this:

> ..../page.html?tid=5

**HTML is here**

```
<select id="form-dropdown-field">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
```

**This is the JS part:**

```
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const tid = parseInt(urlParams.get('tid')) - 1;
        console.log(tid);

        document.getElementById("form-dropdown-field").selectedIndex = tid.toString() ;
```

I get the url parameter value with no problem. It shows `4` in `console.log()` output. But I get the following error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'selectedIndex')**

**UPDATE:**

My script is already in the `<head><script>...</script></head>` tags as @Mina suggests in the comment. And I added the `defer` attribute to `<script>` tag.

Comment: Make sure that execute your script after `DOM` has been loaded by insert the `script` at the end of the body or add `defer` attribute to the `script` tag

Comment: @mina I've tried to move the `<script>` tag to the end of the `<body>` tag. No change. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about `defer` or something else.

I put the js code part after the `select` tag then it now works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <select id="form-dropdown-field">
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            <option value="E">E</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="H">H</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        
            const tid = parseInt(urlParams.get('tid')) - 1;
                
            document.getElementById("form-dropdown-field").selectedIndex = tid;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I've tested this aswell. Seems to work for me if I do what @Mina suggested:

```
<head>
<script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Is there something else happening what could cause this, like is the `<select>` field always present?